# Javascript tool for counting number of times each line is executed

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests, I'd like to actually count the number of times each line of my code has been executed during a run.

For example, I'd like to know something of the following nature:

Given:

```
1. function add(a, b) {
2.   return a + b;
3. }
4. 
5. add(1, 2);
6. add(3, 4);
```

Output:

```
1.  2
2.  2
3.  2
4.  1
5.  1
6.  1
```

The closest thing I can think of would be a code coverage tool such as Istanbul, but my understanding is that these types of tools would tell me *if* a line was executed, not the number of times it was executed.

(Finally, a more complicated program would obviously need to contain source file in addition to line number)

Does such a tool/feature exist?

Comment: In the code coverage of `Istanbul / nyc` tells you how many times the line was executed. (at least with the html reporter)

Comment: @MickaelB. I may not have been clear enough in my question, but this is not for testing purposes. I want to run a script (without tests) and just count line execution. `nyc node index.js` doesn't do much of anything, and without knowing much about Istanbul & most documentation discussing its use with mocha, it's hard to know how to use it as a standalone coverage tool

Comment: For the record, your expected output is incorrect. The function declaration (lines 1 and 3) would only run once.